# Issues working in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting, normals

I have done a rough model with a smart UV projection and when I try to paint on it in texture paint it looks really weird, there are this gradients around the seems that I don't understand.

As seen in the video, when I click face orientation, all faces are blue meaning no flipped normals, I also tried to recalculate the outside in *Edit Mode*, still these weird gradients.

[Video of the issue](https://youtu.be/HMnApfi3XY4)

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (for example just the arms)? https://blend-exchange.com/ don't forget to pack the images before saving

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick reply! I am a bit new to blender, hope this is what you asked for, the .blend-file and the image for the body: https://we.tl/t-QN2MtajbFL

Comment: OK, now its uploaded on stack exchange: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Dnby1QmR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Dnby1QmR/)

Answer (score 0):

You've plugged a *Normal Map* node into the *Principled BSDF* but the selected image is not a normal map image (as you see the color doesn't belong to the normal map color spectrum), plus it doesn't fit the UV. You need to either unplug the *Normal Map* node, or select a correct normal map if there's one:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so much! It worked!